# Alternative to Delete Trigger for tracking deleted records

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, provisioning, sqlbulkcopy

I've got a task to create a large data replication service that will provision our data warehouse. the source databases reside on other servers.

So far, I've been able to implement the Update and Insert items into the warehouse using the conjunction of the SqlBulkCopy class, and the TSql Excepts statement.

my problem now is handling record deletion. the only thing I can think of for handling deletions was to create a custom trigger on the table, to insert deleted records into a temp table that my service could read, and remove from the warehouse.

I know there are a lot of data replication tools out there, but the company wants a custom in house service.

**note** some of the tables that will be provisioned are over 100 million records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you can't do a "soft delete" where you mark a `DELETED` bit column with a `1` once you delete it?

Comment: Oh I wish! these source database systems were actually developed by third party vendors. We get updates from these vendors all the time, and they could be wiping out whole schema's in their updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a Delete trigger would be all that bad.  100 million records is definitely a good chunk, but you're running the trigger on the server, in a way that SQL can optimize the execution path.

If you do something else client side, you're going to incur overhead for fetching the records from the server and then issuing delete commands to the warehouse.

What is it about a trigger that is bothering you?

Comment: that is a very good question. These source databases were installed by third party vendors. I am curious if anyone has come up with alternatives to the trigger technique.

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm reading, you're trying to re-invent replication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).  Does that about sum it up?  If so, my suggestion would be not to.

Comment: you are quite right. can you do replication between an Oracle database & SQL Server database? Could you suggest some "SQL Server Replication For Dummies" links/books?

Comment: You can do replication between Oracle and SQL server (though I don't have any experience with it personally).  If I were starting out, I'd start with the link that I provided (it goes to SQL Books Online) and see what there is to see.  My only advice is to start out simple because there are some nasty twists and turns along the way.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has built-in change tracking (at least in 2008 R2, I'm not sure when exactly this feature was introduced).  Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx

Comment: shucks, that is really neat. unfortunately, it looks like it only works with Sql Server 2008, and I have oracle & SQL server 2005 servers that i need to work as well. thanks for the interesting information though!

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand entirely what you are doing but in SQL Server you can capture the rows that are deleted with the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). Perhaps this is something you can use.

```
-- Table to delete from
declare @T table (id int, name varchar(50))

-- Table to capture the deleted rows
declare @DeletedRows table (id int, name varchar(50))

-- Dummy data
insert into @T values
(1, 'Name1'),
(2, 'Name2'),
(3, 'Name3'),
(4, 'Name4'),
(5, 'Name5')

-- Delete every other row
delete from @T
output deleted.id, deleted.name into @DeletedRows
where id % 2 = 0

select *
from @DeletedRows
```

Result - Deleted rows

```
id          name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
2           Name2
4           Name4
```

Comment: thats neat. never did that before. Unfortunately, the scenario is that i want to avoid any changes to the source database, because they were developed by third party vendors. thanks for your post!

Comment: @N8 – Ok. So you are not the guy in control of deleting. You want to capture the deletions when they happen from your vendors code and keep track of them?

Comment: kinda, We've got some custom code that provisions a data warehouse. we are hitting our third party applications databases directly, and then using some additional logic to give the artifiacts from the third party systems a warehouse key that can be used to join to other system's data within the data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience using triggers to insert record IDs into staging tables. We then created a set of SSIS packages and SQL Agent jobs poll the staging tables and take appropriate action based on the contents of the staging table. This made it possible to implement custom. Since we were moving data between an OLTP system and a warehouse, it made a lot of sense - records don't always line up row for row.